# How can I change or replace layout on the right by clicking on a RecyclerView item on the left same page- android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a layout that is divided into two, the RecyclerView on the left and the details on the right. I would like that when I click an item on the left the layout on the right is replace based on the item clicked. Can someone help me achieve this, or help with a better approach to this. Thank you

[image: Sample image of what I would like]

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I would like to replace the fragment that is on the right. It has to something to do with  

FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction();
                    ft.replace(R.id.details, details);
                    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                    ft.commit();
     
     
But I am not very sure of how to implement it.

Comment: Like i was explan in my answer which i use a Textview for example. You can replace it with fragment. You just have to replace, or add a new fragment to the right in the override funtion. And pass data from activity to that fragment. For more detail how to use fragment it was already have many tutorial, you can search for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this simple solution, use interface.

In your adapter create a interface which is used for implement onClick in your item. Then, call it in `onBindViewHolder`. For example:

```
class YourAdapter(val onclick: OnClickListener): RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    interface OnClickListener {

        fun onClickItem(position: Int)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
                onclick.onClickItem(position) // Here i will pass position for Ex, you can pass anything you want depend on 
                                              //  what's your declared in parameter of onClickItem function
            }
    }
```

Declare adapter and implement interface in your Activity.

```
class YourActivity() : YourAdapter.OnClickListener() {

    lateinit var adapter: YourAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        adapter = YourAdapter(this)
    }

    override fun onClickItem(position: Int) {
        // now you can set content to the view on the right, i've pass position item of recyclerView over here. 
        // content will change based on item you click on the left. 
        // Ex, i have a TextView on the right.
        myTextview.settext(position.toString())
    }
}
```

Comment: Am using Fragment and not Activity, and replace or add doesn't seem to work for me, do The fragment to replace has an id = main_fragment, do you know how I can call replace so that instead of main_fragment, let say with women_fragment. That is what I want. Thanks KiluSs

Comment: Do you mean you want to replace main_fragment to women_fragment by click in recyclerView in another_fragment?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. The items on the left with PLACEHOLDER are the recycleview items that I want to click, then each click need to replace the whole main_fragment to respective ones based on item clicked

Comment: You can use interface like the way i'm implement above to notify activity from another_fragment. After that you can replace or add new women_fragment to the right.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer helped me. But what I did in the onBindViewHolder, I used [position], if the position is say one, then am able to replace the fragment with the new one:

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            if (position == 1) {
            val activity = it.context as AppCompatActivity
                val menFragment = MenFragment()
                   activity.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frameLayout, menFragment)
                    .commit()
            }
        }
```